# jQuery - moving embedded video to top?

Tags: jquery

The code below will find an image if it exists and move it above the title and text.  So, if the markup looks like this:

```
<h2>Some fancy title</h2>
<p>Some interesting text</p>
<img src="someimage.jpg" />
```

or even this:

```
<p><h2>Some fancy title</h2></p>
<img src="someimage.jpg" />
<p>Some interesting text</p>
```

It will reposition elements so that it looks like this:

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" />
<h2>Some fancy title</h2>
<p>Some interesting text
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to rework the code so that if there's a video in the content (whether or not the post also has images), it will move the video above everything else.  Can someone suggest or show me a way to do that?

This is the current code, as I have it right now:

```
$j('#hp-featured-item > div[id^="post-"]').each(function() {
  if($j(this).find('embed')) {
  var id=this.id.match(/^post-([0-9]+)$/);
  var imgt = $j("img:eq(0)");
  var pt = $j("p:not(:has(img)):eq(0)");
  var hh = $j("h2:eq(0)");
  $j(this).html('');
  $j(this).append(imgt).append(hh).append(pt);
  $j(this).each(function() {
   var img = $j('img');
   $j(img).wrap($j('<a>').attr('href', '/blog/?p='+id[1]));
   var h2 = $j('h2');
   $j(h2).wrap($j('<a>').attr('href', '/blog/?p='+id[1]));
  });
  } else {
   var id=this.id.match(/^post-([0-9]+)$/);
   var imgt = $j("embed:eq(0)");
   var pt = $j("p:not(:has(embed)):eq(0)");
   var hh = $j("h2:eq(0)");
   $j(this).html('');
   $j(this).append(imgt).append(hh).append(pt);
   $j(this).each(function() {
    var img = $j('embed');
    $j(img).wrap($j('<a>').attr('href', '/blog/?p='+id[1]));
    var h2 = $j('h2');
    $j(h2).wrap($j('<a>').attr('href', '/blog/?p='+id[1]));
   });
  }
 });
```

Comment: Can you explain further what you are looking to do? Your current code looks like it clears out everything in the post except the first h2, the first img, and the first paragraph that does not contain an image. It then wraps the image in a link, and puts it in front of the h2 or paragraph as needed. Is that your desired result with the embed tag as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is pretty straight forward with jQuery. I put together a test page and a suggested solution. Be sure to look at the source of the test page to see the original HTML content before it was rearranged.

You can view the test page here: http://pixelgraphics.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow/1744585/index.html

Here is the rework of your jQuery code:

```
$j('#hp-featured-item > div[id^="post-"]').each(function() {
    var $div = $j(this),
        $h2  = $div.find('h2:first'),
        $obj = $div.find('object, embed, img').filter(':first'),
        id   = this.id.match(/^post-([0-9]+)$/);

    if( $obj.size() > 0){
        // Find parent
        var $par = $obj.closest('p');

        // Move to top of div
        $obj.prependTo($div);

        // Remove the now empty parent
        $par.remove();

        if( $obj.is('img')){
            // You can't wrap objects and embeds with links, so make sure we just wrap images
            $obj.wrap( $j('<a></a>').attr('href', '/blog/?p='+id[1]));
        }
    }

    // Wrap the contents of the h2, not the h2 itself, with a link
    $h2.wrapInner( $j('<a></a>').attr('href', '/blog/?p='+id[1]) );

});
```

The only thing this doesn't do that your original code seemed to do was to remove all other content except the first img/embed, h2, and paragraph. This leaves the rest of the content in place. If you wanted to do that, then just add this line before the closing `});`:

```
$div.children('p:gt(0)').remove();
```

Comment: This is so great!  Much nicer than what I was trying to do...  Thanks